# Вывод меню по столбцам

Tags: html, css, jquery

Всем привет есть такая врестка

```
<div class="row m-0">
                                    <div class="col-12 col-md m-wrapper">
                                        <div>
                                            <a href="/catalog/detskaya-komnata/podguzniki">
                                                <span>Подгузники</span>
                                            </a>
                                        </div>

                                    </div>
                                    <div class="col-12 col-md m-wrapper">
                                        <div>
                                            <a href="/catalog/detskaya-komnata/podguzniki">
                                                <span>Подгузники</span>
                                            </a>
                                        </div>

                                    </div>
                                    <div class="col-12 col-md m-wrapper">
                                        <div>
                                            <a href="/catalog/detskaya-komnata/podguzniki">
                                                <span>Подгузники</span>
                                            </a>
                                        </div>

                                    </div>
                                    <div class="col-12 col-md m-wrapper">
                                        <div>
                                            <a href="/catalog/detskaya-komnata/podguzniki">
                                                <span>Подгузники</span>
                                            </a>
                                        </div>

                                    </div>
                                </div>
```

И есть данные в БД. Я их получил, но мне надо их вывести согласно это верстке. Как это сделать?

Т.е. есть четыре столпца, циклом начинаю выводить, вставляю в первый столбец, второй, третий, четверты, потом опять в первый второй третий четвертый. Не могу сообразить какой алгоритм сделать?

Comment: Приведите исходный набор данных и желаемый результат. В вашем хтмл примере везде по одной ссылке и не ясно что с этим всем делать, и главное на чем. Вы получаете данные в json и строите на клиенте, или разрулить надо на серверной стороне?

Comment: Честно говоря непонятно какого именно результата вы ожидаете? Ещё, я бы попросил привести в порядок исходный код и более конкретно описать задачу.